# WCF and Json Call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, wcf

I am developing a WCF application and frontend uses JSON to call web methods.

I have a data model class as below

```
   [DataContract]
    public class GL_AccMainTypeListItem
   {
     [DataMember]
     public int accMainTypeyNo { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public string mainType { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public int startAccNo { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public int endAccNo { get; set; }

  }
```

My web method as below and return list of above objects. (These work well)

```
   [OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetDataString/{value}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public List<GL_AccMainTypeListItem> GL_AccMainType_GetAll()
{

        DataAccessService da = new DataAccessService("usp_GL_AccMainTypeGetAll");
        DataTable dt = da.ExecuteDataTable();


        var acc = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                     select new GL_AccMainTypeListItem
                     {
                         accMainTypeyNo = Utility.ToInt(row["accMainTypeNo"]),
                         mainType = Utility.ToString(row["mainType"]),
                         startAccNo = Utility.ToInt(row["startAccNo"]),
                         endAccNo = Utility.ToInt(row["endAccNo"])

                     });

        return acc.ToList();

}
```

Basically here I used stored procedure and get a data table from database and return to client. I want to know  how can I call this web service in client side using JQuery and iterate results set row by row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#btnGetAccountList').click(function () {                  
                    $.ajax({
                          //url will be yourclassname.svc/yourmethodname
                            url: 'namespaceofGL_AccMainType_GetAllmethod.svc/GL_AccMainType_GetAll',
                            method: 'Get',
                            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",                       
                            success: function (data) {
                               //your account detail list will be here. 
                            },
                            error: function (err) {
                                alert(err);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a ajax call to that method.
Eg:

```
// Function to call WCF  Service       
function CallService() {
$.ajax({
    type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: Url, // Location of the service
    data: Data, //Data sent to server
    contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
    dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
    processdata: ProcessData, //True or False
    success: function(msg) {//On Successfull service call
        ServiceSucceeded(msg);
    },
    error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
});
}
```